# .NET 6 - ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback not being called

Tags: .net, ssl-certificate, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to create a custom validation that will ignore SSL errors on specific HTTP requests, most solutions recommend something akin to [creating a custom HttpClientHandler](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/bypass-ssl-certificate-net-core-windows-linux-ios-net/), however when running the following code:

```
HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient(
    new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
        {
            if (policyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (httpRequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString() == "")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
var result = await HttpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

The callback is never called, any breakpoints inside are never hit, however, when creating a  [minimalist example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jmZjWH) the callback does seem to be called.

Is the difference between a console app and a web app causing the callback to not be called? I can't seem to find a reason why the callback isn't being called, even when the HttpClient is declared right before the request is sent.

Comment: I have the same problem. Appeared after installing Windows 11 with a new VS 2022. I even tried to ignore the ssl in windows with the Brandmauer turned off. Only manually downloading certificates and installing them in trusted ones helped. But this is a temporary solution for me.